# Installing passport package, it gives error: reverting ./composer.json to its original content

Tags: laravel-5.5

When I'm installing laravel package passport=~4.0, then it returns

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Currently Laravel Version = 5.5 and PHP Version = 7.2.4
Please give me any solution to resolve this problem in laravel passport setup in windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 3):

I used to use this:

```
composer require paragonie/random_compat:2.* 
composer require laravel/passport=~4.0
```

I've seen it in this [link](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/774)

Answer (score 2):

first of all:
if you are using laravel 6

1. `composer require laravel/passport:7.5.1`
2. in config/app.php add this line:

   ```
   Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
   ```
3. `php artisan migrate`
4. `php artisan passport:install`
   it's done now

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, set the composer.json:

"laravel/passport": "^7.0"

```
 "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
```

execute in console:

composer update